# How to refactor the redundency codes for initiate and update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my controller codes in AngularJS.

```
var dcApp = angular.module("dcApp", ["dcApp.services"])


dcApp.controller("filterController",["$scope", "filterService",
    function ($scope, filterService) {
        var filterSentData = {
            specie: "all",
            cellinfo: "all",
            factor: "all",
            hideincomplete: "show",
            keyword: "",
            clicked: null,
            page: 1
        }
        filterService.setFilterSentData(filterSentData)
        filterService.request().success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.species = data.species
            $scope.cellinfos = data.cellinfos
            $scope.factors = data.factors
            $scope.datasets = data.datasets
        })

        $scope.setFilter = function(key, content) {
            filterSentData[key] = content
            filterService.setFilterSentData(filterSentData)
            filterService.request().success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.species = data.species
                $scope.cellinfos = data.cellinfos
                $scope.factors = data.factors
                $scope.datasets = data.datasets
            })

        }


    }]);
```

As can be found, the `filterService.setFilterSentData(filterSentData)` and `filterService.request().success` snippet are used twice. One for the initiate, and the other for the necessary update when the filter is changed by `setFilter`.. Does anyone have ideas about a good way to refactor the code?

If I want to extract the snippet in a function, should I create the function under `$scope` like `$scope.myfunc = function()` or create directly like `var myfunc = function`?

Comment: Local anonymous function (`var myfunc = function`) is better IMHO, since it doesn't pollute the controller with a method that is only ever called in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored it like this..

```
var dcApp = angular.module("dcApp", ["dcApp.services"])


dcApp.controller("filterController",["$scope", "filterService",
    function ($scope, filterService) {
        var filterSentData = {
            specie: "all",
            cellinfo: "all",
            factor: "all",
            hideincomplete: "show",
            keyword: "",
            clicked: null,
            page: 1
        }

        var filterAjaxUpdate = function(sent) {
            filterService.setFilterSentData(sent)
            filterService.request().success(function (reply, status) {
                $scope.species = reply.species
                $scope.cellinfos = reply.cellinfos
                $scope.factors = reply.factors
                $scope.datasets = reply.datasets
            })
        }

        filterAjaxUpdate(filterSentData)

        $scope.setFilter = function(key, content) {
            filterSentData[key] = content
            filterAjaxUpdate(filterSentData)

        }


    }]);
```